# How to monitor the status of model training running on the server via fast-api

Tags: python, rest, machine-learning, fastapi

By the following code, I want to get the status of training, just if it is started and when it is finished.

```py
app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/train")
async def train_on_background():
    background_tasks.add_task(train, input_data, output_data)




def train(input_data, output_data):
        dataset = prepare_dataset(input_data, output_data)
         
        model = Trainer(dataset)
        model.auto_train()
        
        
        filename = "Model" 
        filename = filename + ".pkl"
        dump(model, open(filename, 'wb'))
```

The `train()` function should train the model by doing several steps. `train_on_background()` should run the train function on the background.

I want to add a separate command to check the training status. the command should respond started when the training starts (`train()` function is called), & finished when it `train()` function is ended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for your problem is by making a temporary file containing the status of the `train()`:

```py
@app.get(“/check”)
def check():
    filename = “Model”
    filename = filename + “.pkl”
    file_exists = os.path.exists(filename)
    if file_exists:
        return {“message”: “Model Already Exists”}
    elif (os.path.exists(f”temp_monitor.txt”)):
         return {“message”: “Training in progress...“}
def monitor_file(text):
    if text is None:
        os.remove(f”temp_monitor.txt”)
    else:
        with open(f’temp_monitor.txt’, ‘w’) as f:
            f.write(text)
```

These 2 functions works on creating a temporary file containing the current status of the training. The `check` command looks for the model if exists to respond with finish.

If the model doesn't exist, it looks for the temporary file, and respond by `training in progress` to indicate that the training was started.

```py
def train(input_data, output_data):4
        dataset = prepare_dataset(input_data, output_data)
        monitor_file(“started”)
        model = Trainer(dataset)
        model.auto_train()
```

Modify your `train` function to save the current status.

Note that you can use this method to save any status you want and check using check command.